# Filter & Map over a Swift Dictionary?

Tags: swift, swift3

I have two methods doing the same thing, one using the more functional Swift.

```
  func getConstraints1(forState newState: State) -> (on: [NSLayoutConstraint], off: [NSLayoutConstraint]) {
    return (
      constraints.filter { $0.key.rawValue == newState.rawValue }.map { $1 }.first!,
      constraints.filter { $0.key.rawValue != newState.rawValue }.map { $1 }.first!
    )
  }
```

The other one using a standard procedural approach.

```
func getConstraints2(for nextState: State) -> (on: [NSLayoutConstraint], off: [NSLayoutConstraint]) {
    var on = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    var off = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    for (state, constraints) in constraints {
      if state == nextState {
        on += constraints
      } else {
        off += constraints
      }
    }

    return (on, off)
  }
```

I feel like `getConstraints2` is going to be faster than `getConstraints1`, but I like the syntax in `getConstraints1`. Is there ever a case fort doing filter/map/reduce operations on a Dictionary? Is this it?

Comment: what is the type of `constraints`, that would help answer.

Comment: As far as I can tell, these two methods do different things – the first returns the first pair of values (of type `[NSLayoutConstraint]`) that meet the given conditions, the second concatenates all the values that meet the given conditions together into two arrays, and returns that pair. Which is correct?

Comment: @Hamish Yeah, I was wondering about that too.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you say `filter` or `map`, you are cycling through the entire sequence. So `getConstraints1` cycles at least twice (maybe four times, but maybe not, because of laziness considerations), whereas `getConstraints2` cycles once.

The question is: do you care? Only you (and Instruments) can answer that one.

Personally, if I were going to deal a deck of cards into two piles (say, all red cards and all black cards), I would work my way through the deck once. Having dealt all the red cards into one pile, I'd feel pretty silly working my way through the deck again looking to see if each remaining card was black.

Answer (score 2):

If your data set is so large that iterating over it twice matters than use function2.  Normally, I wouldn't think it matters because it will still run in O(n).  If you want a functional approach you can alway modify your filter function to return two arrays in a tuple if you are worried about the second iteration.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends what you are map/filter/reduce'ing over since it will iterate over each item, every time one is called. Sometimes using map/filter/reduce can be more readable than larger for loops.

To make `getConstraints2` a bit more functional, you could use a reduce here and it would only iterate over the dictionary once. I did a bit of guessing with the types so hopefully this matches up :)

```
typealias StatefulConstraints = (on: [NSLayoutConstraint], off: [NSLayoutConstraint])

var constraints = [State: [NSLayoutConstraint]]()

func getConstraints3(for nextSate: State) -> StatefulConstraints {
    let initial = (on: [NSLayoutConstraint](), off: [NSLayoutConstraint]())
    return constraints.reduce(initial) { (combined, next: (state: State, constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint])) -> StatefulConstraints in
        var mutableCombined = combined
        if next.state == nextSate {
            mutableCombined.on += next.constraints
        } else {
            mutableCombined.off += next.constraints
        }
        return mutableCombined
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an interesting third way of doing it :)